# How to get CSS background image data from JSON data with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

Below is my Javascript/jQuery script which is working well and background image is changing correctly. But I would like to change backgrounds without touching javascript so I decided to make php script which updates JSON table (which contains background name just for easier manage and url, sample is bottom of this message).

```
setInterval(function () {
     var hours = new Date().getHours();
     $("#hours").html((hours < 10 ? "0" : "") + hours);
 if (hours > 9 && hours < 18) {
      if($("body").css("background-image").indexOf("flower.png")==-1){
          $("body").css("background-image", "url(../assets/flower.png)");
```

So, I would like to get background image flower.png above and mountain.jpg below from JSON. How can I make it? I think there is some CORS request for doing it quite easily.

```
          }
     } else {
          if($("body").css("background-image").indexOf("mountain.jpg")==-1){
             $("body").css("background-image", "url(../assets/mountain.jpg)");
          }
     }
}, 1000);
```

Below is my sample JSON (backgrounds.json) where data should get

> ```
> {"data": [["flower","../assets/flower.png"],["mountain","../assets/mountain.jpg"]]}
> ```